# if I link four bass speakers PDA 1650 does the ohms change

Tags: speakers, ohms

I've got a hpa 3100l amplifier which I want to bridge which is 3400 watts in 8 ohms can I link 4 PD 1650 8 ohm speakers to them without causing damage does the speaker ohms change

Comment: This is likely off topic, but you should include spec sheets for all of those things in your question.

Comment: Hello, welcome to EE.SX. I find nothing relevant when googling "PDA 1650".

Comment: How much power does your amp supply? How many ohms are your speakers?

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar and there's a speaker symbol down near the bottom. Show how they're wired and the speaker ohms in each case.

Comment: You might just want to read the amplifier's documentation. If it's not listed there then you can't do it without modifying the amplifier. And if you had the knowledge how to do that, then you would have done it already and not asked here. So: read the manual !

Answer (score 3):

Wiring four *matching* speakers in a series-parallel arrangement will
result in the amplifier seeing the same impedance as it would see with
one speaker connected, but if the amplifier outputs at a level suitable
for use with a single speaker, each speaker will be 1/4 that loud.  On
the other hand, the amount of power the amplifier can output without the
speakers being damaged or causing distortion would be increased fourfold.

If the speakers have different frequency-response characteristics things
won't work out as nicely, since the power at various frequencies may not
be divided evenly among the speakers.  The actual details are complicated,
if all the speakers are identical, power will be divided identically.